# Help understanding 2N3904 VCE breakdown voltage?

Tags: bjt

While I was designing a constant current source using a 2N3904 I noticed a behavior on the bjt that prompted me to look closer into it.

The issue is that although the datasheet specifies a minimum BVceo = 40V. Any voltage above 8VDC on the collector with base either floating or grounded (as shown on schematic) creates an sudden increase in collector current (suggesting breakdown) and the voltage across C-E is decreased as to limit power across C-E. **I breadboarded the circuit below to investigate this.**

My current mirror is to be used on the output stage of an audio headphone amplifier with Vcc = 12V. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgsVcy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]

Comment: You sure you don't have the collector and emitter switched?

Comment: 8V-9V is roughly what would be expected for the reverse breakdown voltage of the E-B junction. If you do have E and C switched (as @JohnD suggested) you may have noticed your mirror worked, but had low performance because reverse beta is usually relatively low.

Comment: See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpGOKGrcpAk
Here he uses this breakdown voltaje to make an oscillator and shows the curve in Curve Tracer instrument. Indeed he shows it is not only a Breakdown voltage, this also have a little "negative resistance" zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks much for pointing this out. Indeed it seems i was actually looking at the E-B junction reverse breakdown instead. I had my bjt not properly hooked up.